# XPath given node text match get text from child node

Tags: xml, xpath

Given this XML data:

```
<PubmedArticle>
    <MedlineCitation Status="PubMed-not-MEDLINE" Owner="NLM">
        <PMID Version="1">31666891</PMID>
        <Article PubModel="Electronic-eCollection">
            <Journal>
                <ISSN IssnType="Print">1640-5544</ISSN>
                <Title>Journal of human kinetics</Title>
                <ISOAbbreviation>J Hum Kinet</ISOAbbreviation>
            </Journal>
            <ArticleTitle>Relationships between the Expression of the <i>ACTN</i>3 Gene and Explosive Power of Soccer Players.</ArticleTitle>
        </Article>
    </MedlineCitation>
       <MedlineCitation Status="PubMed-not-MEDLINE" Owner="NLM">
        <PMID Version="1">31666892</PMID>
        <Article PubModel="Electronic-eCollection">
            <Journal>
                <ISSN IssnType="Print">1640-5544</ISSN>
                <Title>Journal of human kinetics</Title>
                <ISOAbbreviation>J Hum Kinet</ISOAbbreviation>
            </Journal>
            <ArticleTitle>Cardiovascular and Perceived Effort in Different Head-Out Water Exercises: Effect of Limbs' Action and Resistance Equipment.</ArticleTitle>
        </Article>
    </MedlineCitation> </PubmedArticle>
```

How can I get the text in the node `<ArticleTitle></ArticleTitle>` that matches the text in the node `<PMID></PMID>` that contains '31666891', ie

```
Text='Relationships between the Expression of the <i>ACTN</i>3 Gene and Explosive Power of Soccer Players'
```

I've tried

```
//PMID[text()='31666891']/following::ArticleTitle[1]
```

But it seems messy ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
//PMID[text()='31666891']/../Article/ArticleTitle
```

or, another possibility, this

```
//MedlineCitation[PMID='31666891']/Article/ArticleTitle
```